# Need help tracing the movement of mice in a maze

Tags: c++, recursion, maze

I am now experiencing two problems with tracing the movement of mice in the maze.

1. The tracing gets messy when encountering an up-turn situation or when entering an intersection (especially at the bottom right intersection):
   [Maze tracing gif](https://gfycat.com/gifs/detail/YoungWeightyKilldeer)
2. The mice would leave extra trail behind when looking down at the path it has already passed through(because of the order of my recursion):
   [Extra trails left behind pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDxsb.png)

Here's my code:

```
bool IsValidBlock(char map[30][100], Stack mystack, int x, int y)
{
    if (mystack.Top() == '1' || map[x][y] == 'X')
    {
    return false;
    }
return true;
}

bool MazeTraversal(char map[30][100], Stack mystack, int x, int y)
{
    mystack.push(map[x][y]);

    if (IsValidBlock(map, mystack, x, y) == false && map[x][y] == 'X')
    {

    gotoxy(y, x);
    Sleep(100);
    cout << "R";

    if (map[x][y + 1] == 'X')
    {
        gotoxy(y + 1, x);
        cout << " ";
    }

    if (map[x + 1][y] == 'X')
    {
        gotoxy(y, x + 1);
        cout << " ";
    }
    if (map[x - 1][y] == 'X')
    {
        gotoxy(y, x - 1);
        cout << " ";
    }
    if (map[x][y - 1] == 'X')
    {
        gotoxy(y - 1, x);
        cout << " ";
    }
}

if (IsValidBlock(map, mystack, x, y) == false)
{
    mystack.pop();
    return false;
}
if (mystack.Top() == '0')
{
    gotoxy(y, x);
    Sleep(100);
    cout << "R";

    map[x][y] = 'X'; //marks the visited block
    if (map[x][y + 1] == 'X')
    {
        gotoxy(y + 1, x);
        cout << " ";
    }
    if (map[x + 1][y] == 'X')
    {
        gotoxy(y, x + 1);
        cout << " ";
    }

    if (map[x - 1][y] == 'X')
    {
        gotoxy(y, x - 1);
        cout << " ";
    }
    if (map[x][y - 1] == 'X')
    {
        gotoxy(y - 1, x);
        cout << " ";
    }
}

if (MazeTraversal(map, mystack, x, y + 1)) { return true; } //right
if (MazeTraversal(map, mystack, x + 1, y)) { return true; } //down
if (MazeTraversal(map, mystack, x - 1, y)) { return true; } //up
if (MazeTraversal(map, mystack, x, y - 1)) { return true; } //left

return false;
}
```

I think both problems are caused by the recursive nature of my function

I have tried to mark the path that has already been visited once ('X') by marking it again (not in this code) so it doesn't leave the trail, but it doesn't seem to have helped in anyway

Can someone shed some light on this? Thank you for reading, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this the code for the MazeTraversal function? I can't tell because the beginning of the function is missing.

Comment: Sorry I lost part of the codes during editing. It should be fixed now